# Pic microcontroller voice recording and playback

Tags: pic, audio, speech, recording

I was wondering we can easily interface LCD, led an pot etc but I couldn't find way how to record my different voice strings and playback specific string as per commands that given to pic

Comment: You need to add a _lot_ more detail/context/question to this "question". You haven't asked a question, haven't specified which hardware you're using, haven't specified a goal, and so on.

Comment: Sir or madam I can able to use any pic microcontroller ! But I don't even know what parameters I have to consider for this function ! And for recording I want to use a simple microphones and I don't know in what form I have to convert that for working with pic

Answer (score 2):

At its simplest, voice recording is simply taking regular analog-to-digital (A/D) samples and saving them in memory (temporary or permanent as the application requires.)

And then retrieving the same set of stored sample values and outputting them through a digital-to-analog (D/A) converter. Or even using PWM (pulse-width-modulation) as as common method of producing analog voltage from a digital output pin.

Some of the challenges are: having enough memory to store the relatively large block of data from a few seconds of audio. And then the problem of maintaining a steady sample frequency/pace for recording and for playing back. In many microcontroller chips, you don't necessarily have complete control over the exact timing of things like A/D and D/A with enough dependability for reasonably quality audio.

That is why there are "voice recorder" chips and whole board sub-assemblies that are pre-engineered specifically for the task. They are optimized for recording, storage and playback.

Here are some examples (just one of many available)
* Example voice recorder chips: http://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/isd-chipcorder/12724 
* Example voice recorder board: http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/252117334430

Comment: Thank you Richard sir for very use ful answer ! I don't want to record data in every system but once if I have recorded some strings then only I want these different raws of speech and I want to play these recorded speech at different time ! Like if I press 1 button then play " voice 1 " if I press button 2 then "voice 2 " ! Q

Comment: There are commercial products that do exactly what you are asking for.  Examples: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13720 ; http://www.ebay.com/itm/Micro-SD-TF-Card-MP3-WAV-Player-Board-Module-RS232-TTL-external-IO-C6-6-/301631462414

Comment: Sir it's not about buying I want to learn and make own one!